# How to increase space from col and negativ margin from row

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I am using barrio theme for drupal with bootstrap 5 and i would like to increase the space between columns everywhere.
I know the gutter class gx-5 but i dont wont to put it everywhre.

In my css i put this to get a 40px space and not only 30px.

```css
.col, .col-1, .col-10, .col-11, .col-12, .col-2, .col-3, .col-4, .col-5, .col-6, .col-7, .col-8, .col-9, .col-auto, .col-lg, .col-lg-1, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-auto, .col-md, .col-md-1, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-auto, .col-sm, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-auto, .col-xl, .col-xl-1, .col-xl-10, .col-xl-11, .col-xl-12, .col-xl-2, .col-xl-3, .col-xl-4, .col-xl-5, .col-xl-6, .col-xl-7, .col-xl-8, .col-xl-9, .col-xl-auto {
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.row {
    margin-right: -40px;
    margin-left: -40px;
}
```

In most cases it works fine, but in nested row / column structures not.
I think i have to put more style in the css.
In this case, it is not possible to work with scss, therefore i can not change one variable but do it for all margins and paddings, where necessary.
Ist there a good trick?

Comment: try to create a snippet. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry, Behrouz. I dont understand,what i have to do. Or did You change my code?
What could i do better?
My english is not so good...